# Does tensorflow support to calculate the cross entropy loss of a subset of labels for semantic segmentation?

Tags: python, tensorflow, semantic-segmentation

I am doing a semantic segmentation task using tensorflow. I have 5 classes, I calculate the loss like this:

```
loss = tf.reduce_mean((tf.nn.sparse_softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(logits=logits, labels=tf.squeeze(annotation, squeeze_dims=[3]), name="entropy")))
```

`logits` has shape (batch_size, picture_height, picuture_width, 5)

`annotation` has shape (batch_size, picture_height, picuture_width, 1)

Now I only want to calculate the loss of the first 4 classes, ignore the 5th class. How can I achieve this?

For example, if I only want to calulate the Cohen's kappa of the first 4 classes, I can set the `labels` parameter in sklearn.metrics.cohen_kappa_score:

```
kappa = cohen_kappa_score(y_true, y_pred, labels=[0,1,2,3])
```

Comment: So what you mean is, you compute the softmax with the five logit values, then the cross-entropy, but wherever the class was 5 just mask that value? And then the mean should be done over all the elements, zeroing the 5 class cross-entropy, or only over the non-5 elements?

Comment: Just compute the cross entropy loss of non-5 pixels.

Answer (score 0):

You can use not sparse version of cross entropy loss that accepts one-hot labels [tf.losses.softmax_cross_entropy](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/losses/softmax_cross_entropy), and manually create one-hot vector using [tf.one_hot](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/one_hot).

It accepts `depth` argument that allows to use only first labels, or you can just slice result one-hot encoded tensor before passing to the loss.